# How Do I Automate ETL tests on Data Warehouse project using .NET?

Tags: sql, automated-tests, etl, data-warehouse

I have been given the following requirements to create an automated test suite for our data warehouse project. Sources data comes from disparate locations including: xml, oracle, mysql, services. Target systems include, Excel, SQL Server DB, CSV, XML files.

1. The requirement is to **use c# as a language**.
2. There is no plan to get a commercial tool.
3. We want to be able to include this process as a part of CI/CD pipeline such that tests will automatically execute on code deploy.

Up to now we have used a bunch of SQL queries and eye balling results but this is not enough to tackle the many scenarios reflected in the data.

I have managed to create assemble these queries into a stored procedure where each writes results into a table. We then match the results against expected results. This does not handle tests where target is a csv for example.

The ideal scenario is to drive everything from a c# solution. Not sure how this works.

Has anyone done anything similar **in C#** or have any ideas please?

Comment: So you have a partial solution but you want to test things like CSV's? Can you just hash the CSV file and compare that to an expected hash? I've also had this same requirement but never had time to come up with a satisfactory solution. The main issue for me is that it has always been difficult to "spin" off a correct representaion of the data warehouse. One point to make is that if your data warehouse has constraints, FK's, primary keys, defaults, unique constraints etc. then there is already some data domain checking built in (problem is it only gets caught at runtime)

Comment: Also FYI, Visual Studio does have database unit tests built in (they have a bit of C# behind them). I've never had the opportunity to implement them properly though. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/walkthrough-creating-and-running-a-sql-server-unit-test?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I am wondering if I should use SSIS for this project but not quite sure if it will allow me organise tests into folders etc. Again, wondering how to hook up SSIS project to CI/CD process

Comment: I can't help you decide whether to use SSIS or not. It certainly doesn't allow you to organise things into folders in the VS solution, but it does in the SSIS Catalog. If you're wondering how to hook it up to the CI/CD process, do some googling. What CI/CD tool will you use or will you try and roll your own?

Comment: The *automation* part in ETL test is only the minor issue. The big deal is in getting the *expected state* after the ETL job is finshed. Here are you *very far* from the typical `OLTP JUnit` schema testing `1 + 1 = 2` (i.e. reimplement the sum in the JUnit test and compare the results). No tool comes to help here but a hard manual work. Of course if your DWH schema is *denormalized*  the consistency can be easy automatically checked.

Comment: The bitter reality is that you will, most likely have to build it yourself. Pretty much, a 
 Custom testing framework - spin testing around the developers' tools (i.e. SQL Server Management Studio, mySQL Workbench, Pentaho, Jaspersoft, Birt etc.).  DWH testing is data centric, so data quality is a major concern. You can read more, of my experience here:

http://automationisking.blogspot.com/p/how-to-test-your-data-warehouse.html

Since, your first requirement is to use C#, I would say that an ORM like Entity Framework will do the job

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/

Comment: @ekostadinov, et al Thanks for all your comments. I ended up using SSIS in addition to custom c# code. There is no ready made, one size fits all solution really. SSIS was the perfect need for my task.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber wow that kind of detailed info is rare as hens teeth - that's a very thorough and usefule article